# Error in farver using color palettes for leaflet in R

Tags: r, colors, leaflet, gis

The color palette for leaflet is not working in linux. The error is farver related. Using the exact same example for leaflet from [RStudio](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/colors.html):

```
    # Call the color function (colorNumeric) to create a new palette function
pal <- colorNumeric(c("red", "green", "blue"), 1:10)
```

Returns this error on linux *but not* on windows:

```
Error in farver::decode_colour(colors, alpha = TRUE, to = "lab", na_value = "transparent") : 
      unused argument (na_value = "transparent")
```

I've updated all packages, look a bit into the source code for the farver package, but I'm at a loss as to why this works in windows and not linux. Seems like a *very* straight forward piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a older version of farver or scales packages.

Comment: which one and how to download it ?